Repopulate treeview with gspread-based dataframe after data append and deletion
I'm using gspread to create the contents of a dataframe, and then that dataframe populates a treeview. After I use entry boxes and a button to append a new row, the goal is for the data to clear and the treeview repopulate with the updated dataframe. Appending a row to the dataframe and the google sheet works. Deleting the contents of the treeview works and then it refills with the original dataframe. Is there a way to create a new dataframe within the scope of the same function appending the row? I included sample code:
self.si = spi.SpreadsheetInfo()
self.user = user
self.sess_m = self.si.sessions
self.sess_loc = self.sess_m.loc[self.sess_m['Provider'] == self.user]

self.sess_rows = self.sess_loc.tail(100)
self.session_rows = self.sess_rows.to_numpy().tolist()

self.si.range3.append_row(self.new_date, table_range='A3:N3')
self.session_tree.delete(*self.session_tree.get_children()) #working


for row in self.sd.session_rows: #rows not updated
    self.session_tree.insert("","end",values=row)


If by "not working" you mean that the tree remains empty after deleting the rows, I guess you need to check that "self.sd.session_rows" is not empty.

@8349697 I checked and it's not empty.

The loop and insert look fine. It needs to run it to understand what's wrong with the code. Provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem. Specifically, the part that deals with tkinter (creating a treeview,  functions that manipulate rows and "self.sd.session_rows", etc.). Also provide an example of the data in "self.sd.session_rows".

@8349697 let me know if you encounter anything missing

Please delete this question (immediately) and never post your credentials online. I can't reproduce your problem because of a bunch of undefined variables. "self.sd.session_rows" is not defined and there is no part of the code where this data comes from. The Treeview part looks normal. With dummy data it deletes and populates the rows. self.ins.insert(0,'') raises AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'insert' (should be self.ins.set() I think?). Make sure you don't use the same variable names for different objects. This can lead to unexpected code behavior.

@8349697 I figured out the main issue and deleted most of the code from the question

If you only need the last 100 rows of a sheet (tail), and no one else is adding rows to that sheet, don't overwrite the tree rows completely. Just delete the first row and insert one row to the end. (in "def sessionadd"). It makes sense to do the same here with "self.sd.session_rows".

@8349697 while I appreciate that suggestion, multiple people will be using the program and adding to the sheet. The treeview shows a filtered view of the sheet (hence self.sess_loc).

If the data can be changed at any time, you can check whether changes have been made to the sheet. You can check if Google Sheets API can provide some kind of edit notification. If not, you can schedule a background task (with a certain time interval between requests). This can be done using the threading module or the tkinter after method. There is also a method of the Spreadsheet class that may be useful.
